# wait for .each & contained database update then redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ionic-framework

```
function add(one, two, three) {
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO results (one, two, three) VALUES (?,?,?)', [one, two, three]);
    }), function () {
         console.log('add transaction ok');
    });
}

$('#add').click(function () {
  $("tr.row").each(function () {
    var one = $(this).find("input.one").val();
    var two = $(this).find("input.two").val();
    var three = $(this).find("input.three").val();
    add(one, two, three);
  });

  alert("Done");
});
```

Hi, I'm trying to click a button which will find input values in each row of a table and insert these value into a database. the amount of table rows will vary sometimes maybe 3 other times maybe 10.

I have used the jquery .each function to do this where an async function is invoked. This whole process works. What i'm trying to do now is when the .each() function is complete to make an alert(). with the code as it is, i receive the alert first and then the console log that the transaction was okay but i want to get the alert last.

Instead of the alert ideally i want to direct to another page but i can not if the transaction doesn't complete first.

I have looked at the following solution available in this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12424/wait-for-each-contained-async-calls-to-complete-before-redirect. implementing this the alert is made straight away and the transaction call is not even started.

Answer (score 0):

First - I'm not sure you should be writing SQL from the client. An ajax request containing the values you want to add should be sent to the server and then the server should update the database so no one can hack at your query. So you've been warned. But here's how to do this in the client:

Updating your database is an asynchronous task. You need to provide a callback or return a promise to be notified when your update is complete:

```
function add(one, two, three) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO results (one, two, three) VALUES (?,?,?)', [one, two, three]);
    }, function (res) {
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}

$('#add').click(function () {
  $("tr.row").each(function () {
    var one = $(this).find("input.one").val();
    var two = $(this).find("input.two").val();
    var three = $(this).find("input.three").val();
    add(one, two, three).then(function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm not sure how your `db.transation` handles failures but you'll need to call the `reject` handler there (e.g. `reject(err)`).

Edit: you may want to consider using `Promise.all` if you want to wait for all of the rows to update instead of reacting to them as they respond (this may or may not be a good fit for your use case)

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var promiseList = $('tr.row').map(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var one = $this.find('input.one').val();
        var two = $this.find('input.two').val();
        var three = $this.find('input.three').val();

        return add(one, two, three);
    });

    Promise.all(promiseList).then(function (resultRows) {
        resultRows.forEach(function (rowTransactionResult, index) {
            // do something with each result
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: hey, i'm making a phonegap mobile application, the database is the devices native storage which the app uses.

edit: im trying to make the alert after each completes, your solution is within each?

Comment: If the database is local to the device then by all means this will work. I have no idea what your app is or does so I can't conclusively say whether or not this approach is actually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a promise to manage async tasks.

```js
function add(one, two, three) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      setTimeout(function() { resolve([one, two, three]) }, 2000);
    } catch (e) {
      reject('oops!');
    }
  });
}

$('.button').on('click', function() {
  add(1, 2, 3).then(function(res) {
    alert(res);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click me!</button>
```